# Unit testing async method: How to explicitly assert that the internal task was cancelled

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, async-await, cancellationtokensource

I was recently writing an *async* method that calls a external long running *async* method so I decided to pass *CancellationToken* enabling cancellation. The method can be called concurrently.

Implementation has combined *exponential backoff* and *timeout* techniques described in [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary)'s book *Concurrency in C# Cookbook* as follows;

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets bar
/// </summary>
/// <param name="cancellationToken">The cancellation token that cancels the operation</param>
/// <returns>A <see cref="Task"/> representing the task of setting bar value</returns>
/// <exception cref="OperationCanceledException">Is thrown when the task is cancelled via <paramref name="cancellationToken"/></exception>
/// <exception cref="TimeoutException">Is thrown when unable to get bar value due to time out</exception>
public async Task FooAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    TimeSpan delay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250);
    for (int i = 0; i < RetryLimit; i++)
    {
        if (i != 0)
        {
            await Task.Delay(delay, cancellationToken);
            delay += delay; // Exponential backoff
        }

        await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync(cancellationToken); // Critical section is introduced for long running operation to prevent race condition

        using (CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken))
        {
            cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout));
            CancellationToken linkedCancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

            try
            {
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                bar = await barService.GetBarAsync(barId, linkedCancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

                break;
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) when (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                if (i == RetryLimit - 1)
                {
                    throw new TimeoutException("Unable to get bar, operation timed out!");
                }

                // Otherwise, exception is ignored. Will give it another try
            }
            finally
            {
                semaphoreSlim.Release();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder if I should write a unit test that explicitly asserts that the internal task `barService.GetBarAsync()` is cancelled whenever `FooAsync()` is cancelled. If so how to implement it cleanly?

On top of that, should I ignore implementation details and just test what client/caller is concerned as described in method summary (bar is updated, cancel triggers `OperationCanceledException`, timeout triggers `TimeoutException`).

If not, should I get my feet wet and start implementing unit tests for following cases:

1. Testing it is thread-safe (monitor acquired only by single thread at a time)
2. Testing the retry mechanism
3. Testing the server is not flooded
4. Testing maybe even a regular exception is propagated to caller

Comment: This is more about testing philosophy, so there's probably no definitive answer, but I lean towards testing the public interface only.  BarService is its own type, so you should test that with its own tests, not with this one.  Testing the combination as you suggest is more a test of the CLR's Cancellation mechanism than your code, and we should be able to assume that's okay.  If - as I think you're implying - BarService is internal, you can use InternalsVisibleTo (only for the tests assembly) to allow testing it (but some will surely disagree).

Comment: @sellotape I'm testing `FooAsync()` on it's own fixture (Foo) _mocking_  `BarService.GetBarAsync()`. However, it reacts to it's dependencies behavior and that's what I'm considering about testing. So basically; if you'r implying that I should only test the general behavior instead of implementation details, do you think I should test against _thread safety_ given that I'm stating that the method is thread safe.

Comment: If you're mocking it then there is nothing really to test _for it specifically_ and you can test it in isolation.  Re thread safety, yes you probably _should_ test that aspect of it if it's part of the public contract.  I'll leave the finer details to you, but an initial thought is to assert that GetBarAsync() is only called once up to a particular point in time, when FooAsync() is called from 2 threads at roughly the same time.  You can Setup your GetBarAsync() (mocked) method to delay a little to avoid too much of a race.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I wonder if I should write a unit test that explicitly asserts that the internal task barService.GetBarAsync() is cancelled whenever FooAsync() is cancelled.

It would be easier to write a test that asserts that the *cancellation token* passed to `GetBarAsync` is cancelled whenever the cancellation token passed to `FooAsync` is cancelled.

For asynchronous unit testing, my signal of choice is `TaskCompletionSource<object>` for asynchronous signals and `ManualResetEvent` for synchronous signals. Since `GetBarAsync` is asynchronous, I'd use the asynchronous one, e.g.,

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(); // passed into FooAsync
var getBarAsyncReady = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
var getBarAsyncContinue = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
bool triggered = false;
[inject] GetBarAsync = async (barId, cancellationToken) =>
{
  getBarAsyncReady.SetResult(null);
  await getBarAsyncContinue.Task;
  triggered = cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested;
  cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
};

var task = FooAsync(cts.Token);
await getBarAsyncReady.Task;
cts.Cancel();
getBarAsyncContinue.SetResult(null);

Assert(triggered);
Assert(task throws OperationCanceledException);
```

You can use signals like this to create a kind of "lock-step".

---

Side note: in my own code, I never write retry logic. I use [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly), which is fully `async`-compatible and thoroughly tested. That would reduce the semantics that need to be tested down to:

1. The CT is passed through (indirectly) to the service method, resulting in `OperationCanceledException` when triggered.
2. There is also a timeout, resulting in `TimeoutException`.
3. Execution is mutex'ed.

(1) would be done just like the above. (2) and (3) are less easy to test (for proper tests, requiring either MS Fakes or abstractions for time/mutex). There is definitely a point of diminishing returns when it comes to unit testing, and it's up to you how far you want to go.

Comment: Thanks for answering Stephen. I like this approach since I'm trying to avoid unstable/unreliable `Delay` solutions. So, again with the cases to test, in this particular example how far would you go?

Comment: It depends on several factors. I'd do (1) in any case, and consider doing (2) if it was just me (teams usually don't have Fakes available). I haven't gone as far as (3) yet.

Comment: [Polly's tests for its mutex policy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/e9269ad9d24b9e0bd0cde546343d0c4d1539b77c/src/Polly.SharedSpecs/Bulkhead/BulkheadAsyncSpecs.cs#L94) (part 3 in Stephen's numbering) coincidentally also demonstrate some of the testing techniques Stephen mentions / Saro asked about.  [TaskCompletionSource<object>](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/e9269ad9d24b9e0bd0cde546343d0c4d1539b77c/src/Polly.SharedSpecs/Helpers/TraceableAction.cs#L18) is used as a proxy with which to simulate completed / cancelled async work. ...

Comment: .. and an [AutoResetEvent](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/e9269ad9d24b9e0bd0cde546343d0c4d1539b77c/src/Polly.SharedSpecs/Bulkhead/BulkheadSpecsHelper.cs#L19) is used to [signal from the system-under-test](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/e9269ad9d24b9e0bd0cde546343d0c4d1539b77c/src/Polly.SharedSpecs/Helpers/TraceableAction.cs#L30) to [the test harness](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/e9269ad9d24b9e0bd0cde546343d0c4d1539b77c/src/Polly.SharedSpecs/Bulkhead/BulkheadSpecsHelper.cs#L51), to avoid the unreliable introduction of delay into tests, which @SaroTaşciyan mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Stephen Cleary for the nod to [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) retry.  Perhaps of interest to future readers, all the functionality in the original poster's code sample could now be built from ready-made Polly primitives which are already unit-tested:

- [Timeout policy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout) for timeout by timing-out cancellation token (including combining with a user-supplied cancellation token)
- [Bulkhead policy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Bulkhead) for parallelization throttling/mutual exclusion
- [WaitAndRetry](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/master/README.md#wait-and-retry) for retry, including cancellation during waits
- [PolicyWrap](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap) to combine.

All Polly policies are [fully unit-tested](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/tree/master/src/Polly.SharedSpecs), sync and async-compatible, thread-safe for concurrent executions, and have pass-through cancellation support.

So, the intention of the original code could be achieved something like:

```
Policy retry = Policy.Handle<WhateverExceptions>().WaitAndRetryAsync(RetryLimit, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250 * Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)));
Policy mutex = Policy.BulkheadAsync(1);
Policy timeout = Policy.TimeoutAsync(/* define overall timeout */);

bar = await timeout.WrapAsync(retry).WrapAsync(mutex).ExecuteAsync(ct => barService.GetBarAsync(barId, ct), cancellationToken);
```

---

I'll add some comments about unit-testing (the OP's original question) to the comments to Stephen's (much more relevant) answer to that.

Comment: Thanks you for the information you shared. Also thumbs up for Polly which makes life in an concurrent context much easier (: